# iPhone/Objective-C: How to modify UILabel from timer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, timer

I have the following timer:

```
uploadGPS_timer=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0 target:self selector:@selector(uploadGPS_tick:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
[self uploadGPS_tick:nil];
```

And here is the callback: uploadGPS_tick():

```
-(void)uploadGPS_tick:(NSTimer*)timer{
    if(!lat || !lng){
        //do nothing
    }else{
        NSString *urlStr=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://www.example.com/ajax/updateCoords.php"];
        NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:urlStr];

        __block ASIFormDataRequest *request=[[ASIFormDataRequest alloc ]initWithURL:url];
        [request setPostValue:lat forKey:@"lat"];
        [request setPostValue:lng forKey:@"lng"];
        NSLog(@"EOH: %@",lat);
        [request setDelegate:self];
        [request setCompletionBlock:^{
            NSString *response=[request responseString];
            NSLog(@"%@",response);

            if([response isEqualToString:@"LO"]){
                [self.navigationItem setBackBarButtonItem:nil];
                DriverLogin *x= [[DriverLogin alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
                [[self navigationController]pushViewController:x animated:NO];
            }

            SBJsonParser *parser=[[SBJsonParser alloc]init];
            NSMutableDictionary *obj=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init ];
            obj=[[parser objectWithString:[request responseString] error:nil]retain];

            credits.text=[[obj objectForKey:@"credits"] stringValue];   //this won't show...
            creditsUsed.text=[[obj objectForKey:@"creditsUsed"] stringValue];   //this won't show...
            NSInteger timeLeftSecs=[[obj objectForKey:@"creditTimeLeft"] intValue];
            NSInteger timeLeftMins=(int)(timeLeftSecs/60);
            creditTimeLeft.text=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%d",timeLeftMins];   //this won't show...

            NSLog(@"xxx:%@",obj);

        }];
        [request setFailedBlock:^{
            NSError *error =[request error];
            NSLog(@"%@",error);
            //do nothing
        }];
        [request startAsynchronous];
    }
}
```

As you can see, every five seconds, a JSON object is sent from the server. This JSON object is then parsed and three UILabels are set based on this JSON data.

The trouble I'm having is that the UILabels aren't getting their text set! Even though I can clearly see `NSLog(@"xxx:%@",obj);` in the debugger. The UILabels are connected properly in the .xib.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: UI elements can only be updated from the main loop. Are you sure you are running on the main loop for the UI update code?

Comment: Mmm. I don't know. How to check this? Many thanks,

Comment: `ASIHTTPRequest` always calls back on the main thread.

Comment: Can you think of any way around this?

Comment: why you set a requestDelegate when you create the Completion and Error blocks? and you should define "self" as a "__block" var.

Comment: @Lvsti I read this in the docs too, but did you really test this? Mind that we don't have multithreading here not only by the asynchronous request, but also by the timer.

Comment: After all, it smells like a threading thing ... I'd first try to add some code that excludes the timer and triggers the request from the GUI. If the behavior's the same, try without asynchronous requests.

Comment: @Kai I know that timers are just scheduled in the runloop but ASIHTTP does use a background thread for performing its requests. However, the last time I dug into the code it was calling back the completion blocks/selectors on the main thread, so in theory that shouldn't be the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do it from main thread. Replace the label text assignment with following code:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    creditTimeLeft.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",timeLeftMins];

});
```